# How to run two virtual X11 screens on a single monitor?

Tags: x11

I would like to be able to emulate a dual monitor set up using a single physical display. Ideally, X11 would be able to treat each left/right half of the monitor as a separate display. Is this possible with X11?

*EDIT:*

I've cobbled together some crude images to attempt to better clarify what my intent is.

Imagine the following dual monitor set up:

[image]

Since I only have a single, large, widescreen monitor, I would like X11 to believe that the single physical display is actually two displays; each taking up a horizontal half of the physical display space, as follows:

[image]

Comment: No, but with xnest and tiling WM you can do something like that.

Comment: That depends on what you want to emulate or what you want to do/test/proove with your emulated environment. X has quite some abstraction going on before actual screens become (X-) screens and even more before they become (the visible part of) your working area

Comment: @Eddy_Em: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I think Eddy is just referring to the fact that with the right window manager (or tool -- check the wikipedia article on xnest) you should be able to do something that might be considered effectively *similar*, but I really think YOU should be more specific about what you are trying to accomplish, then you will get more specific answers ;)  A *real* dual monitor setup with X can mean several fairly different things, so...

Comment: @noffle, I mean that you can set up some of tiling WM so, that after login will run two windowed xnest sessions by half of screen each. But that would be two different X-sessions, so you won't be able to move windows between them.

BTW, tiling WM itself could be setup like you want. Tell more detailed what do you mean.

Comment: Let me rephrase: WHY do you want to do that? Usually, X11 creates one unified display out of many physical screens. If you first fake your 1 screen to be actually 2, X will take them and make one out of them. So, what is the actual goal?

Comment: @user1129682: Most WMs are aware that there are multiple displays present. e.g. a tiling WM wouldn't stretch a single window across both of your monitors.

Comment: @noffle: yes, WMs have some special characteristics. They still work on the one X display that X creates, even though they can be aware of the physical screens